# I think Splice(remove) method works as exactly opposite of its actual work

Tags: javascript, react-native, splice

I am expecting to only remove the given index in "deleteNumber" method . But It's doing exactly the opposite. It removes all indexes except given index.

Javascript code:

```
deleteNumber = (index) => {
    console.log("index: ", index);
    this.setState((state) => {
        const numbers = state.numbers.splice(index, 1);
        this.storeData('numbers', JSON.stringify(numbers));
        return(
        {
            numbers: numbers,
        }
        )
    })
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. I guessed splice returns the new array that contains all item except removed item. But actually it returns a array of removed item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Splice alters the given array and returns the elements it removed.
Something like this will set state to the new (altered) array.

```
deleteNumber = (index) => {
  let numbers = this.state.numbers;
  numbers.splice(index, 1);
  this.setState({
    numbers
  });
}
```